# It's time to change your password not working in Magento 2.4.6 admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.6, magento-admin

It's time to change your password link not working when I click on it, it simply redirects to same page(admin dashboard).

I have set **Password Change** setting to **Recommended**, I don't want **Forced**.

Don't know what is going wrong it is fresh Magento 2.4.6 setup.

[image]

Comment: $myAccountUrl = $this->url->getUrl('adminhtml/system_account/');
$message = __('It\'s time to <a href="%1">change your password</a>.', $myAccountUrl);

Issue seems to be here key value in href is creating issue.